# Live Streaming Video On App Inventor

Tags: android, video-streaming, app-inventor

There is a live streaming video in one of my app which is from one of the websites http://shirdisaiholidays.com/live-dharsan-3/.

I used activity starter with URI as `rtsp://cam.live-s.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn-live2-b1/_definst_/cam/live/secure/feed022/playlist.m3u8?e=0&h=ba7f5c5f6bf8a02d29f909dfa8d0c075`.
It worked for some time but now it has stopped altogether. Someone said I can use video player or player with the url as source which I have also used without any success. It shows an `error 702`. Other apps using the same live streaming are working fine.

Comment: see this thread https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/8ATSTdf8_n4/osDv3IdlrsoJ